# How can I change the default port (8333) of Bitcoin Core on Ubuntu 20 LTS?

Tags: ubuntu, port, tor, core, bitcoin

I am trying to set up a second machine on my network to run Bitcoin Core. As I’m port-forwarding on my router port 8333 already (the default port of Bitcoin Core), I can’t use the same port on my second machine. So far I have been unsuccessful in finding documentation on how to change on Bitcoin Core itself the default port.

Possible solutions:
 1. Change settings in Bitcoin Core. As said above, no luck so far.
 2. Bitcoin Core through Tor. Is this even possible? Does this solve the port issue?
 3. Port-forward in Ubuntu via Firewall (gufw?). Again, I don’t know how to do this.

My VPN (NordVPN) does not allow port-forwarding, so currently I run this “unprotected”. I was hoping a Tor solution plus a change of port can solve my issues.

Can someone pls assist? Many thanks!

Comment: To encourage a more positive response, I recommend you include some details regarding the steps you have taken so far to solve your issue.

Comment: @Owen added much more info as suggested

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting up a Socks5proxy server on the machine running Bitcoin-Core and the forwarded port on your router. For the second machine to run Bitcoin-core, you should have the traffic from your 2nd machine route through the socks5proxy server installed on your first machine. This should work fine and doesnt face the roadblock of setting up forwarded ports on both machines. In this case, you can run N number of Bitcoin nodes behind a router, with the traffic of N-1 machines going through the IP and Socks5 proxy of the machine setup with port forwarding.

I have never done this but its definitely worth a try. Check out -->
https://community.hetzner.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-danted-proxy-socks5

and I would recommend your Sock5 proxy port to be 8333, although that might not be necessary.